# TypeError: 'Series' object does not support item assignment while benchmarking Dask vs Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, dask

after two sentiment analysis, I need to do a Dasklib vs Pandas comparison in a benchmark way. I though I had it until I ran into the TypeError: 'Series' object does not support item assignment.

This is my code:

```
# %%
import sys
sys.path.append('/Users/rokayadarai/Desktop/Coding/DataSets')

# %%
# Mongo DB init
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost", 27017)
db = client['Hotel_Test']
collection = db['collection']

# %%
# DASK
import dask.dataframe as ddf

def run_dask():
    #read data
    df_dask = ddf.read_csv('/Users/rokayadarai/Desktop/Coding/DataSets/Hotel_Reviews.csv')
    df_dask = df_dask.dropna()
    df_dask = df_dask.sample(frac = 0.05)

    #devide dataset into negative and positive sets and assign correct boolean rating
    negative = df_dask['Negative_Review']
    positive = df_dask['Positive_Review']

    #additional cleaning
    negative = negative.drop_duplicates()
    positive = positive.drop_duplicates()

    negative = negative.to_frame()
    positive = positive.to_frame()

    cleaned_negative_reviews = negative['Negative_Review']
    cleaned_positive_reviews = positive['Positive_Review']

    cleaned_negative_reviews['rating'] = 0
    cleaned_positive_reviews['rating'] = 1

    #write negative and positive reviews to csv files
    cleaned_negative_reviews.to.csv('/Users/rokayadarai/Desktop/Coding/DataSets/dask_negative_reviews.csv')
    cleaned_positive_reviews.to.csv('/Users/rokayadarai/Desktop/Coding/DataSets/dask_positive_reviews.csv')

    print('Dask done')

# %%
# PANDAS
import pandas as pd

def run_pandas():
    #read data
    df = pd.read_csv('/Users/rokayadarai/Desktop/Coding/DataSets/Hotel_Reviews.csv')
    df = df.dropna()
    df = df.sample(frac=0.05)

    #devide dataset into negative and positive sets and assign correct boolean rating
    negative = pd.DataFrame(df['Negative_Review'])
    positive =  pd.DataFrame(df['Positive_Review'])

    #additional cleaning
    reviews_negative = negative[negative["review"] != "No Negative"]
    reviews_positive = positive[positive["review"] != "No Positive"]

    cleaned_negative_reviews = reviews_negative['review']
    cleaned_positive_reviews = reviews_positive['review']

    cleaned_negative_reviews['rating'] = 0
    cleaned_positive_reviews['rating'] = 1

    #write negative and positive reviews to csv files
    cleaned_negative_reviews.to.csv('/Users/rokayadarai/Desktop/Coding/DataSets/pandas_negative_reviews.csv')
    cleaned_positive_reviews.to.csv('/Users/rokayadarai/Desktop/Coding/DataSets/pandas_positive_reviews.csv')

    print('Pandas done')
    
    # %%
    # denfine benchmark
import time

def benchmark(function, function_name):
        start = time.time()
        function()
        end = time.time()
        print('{0} seconds for {1}'.format((end - start), function_name))
# %%
benchmark(run_dask, 'dataframe dask')
benchmark(run_pandas, 'dataframe pandas')

# %%
```

and this is the error Traceback:

```
benchmark(run_dask, 'dataframe dask')...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~/Desktop/Coding/py /DASK_vs_PANDAS.py in 
----> 87 benchmark(run_dask, 'dataframe dask')
      88 benchmark(run_pandas, 'dataframe pandas')

~/Desktop/Coding/py /DASK_vs_PANDAS.py in benchmark(function, function_name)
      4 def benchmark(function, function_name):
      5     start = time.time()
----> 6     function()
      7     end = time.time()
      8     print('{0} seconds for {1}'.format((end - start), function_name))

~/Desktop/Coding/py /DASK_vs_PANDAS.py in run_dask()
     36     cleaned_positive_reviews = positive['Positive_Review']
     37 
---> 38     cleaned_negative_reviews['rating'] = 0
     39     cleaned_positive_reviews['rating'] = 1
     40 

TypeError: 'Series' object does not support item assignment
```

The error occurs as soon as I run the last cell. Could someone tell me please what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please distil the part of your code that is causing the problem. You are reporting a dask problem, so there should be no mongo or direct pandas part to this, or indeed any benchmarking.

Comment: Done! It worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

for dask you would want to do

```
cleaned_negative_reviews = cleaned_negative_reviews.assign(rating = 0)
cleaned_positive_reviews = cleaned_positive_reviews.assign(rating = 1)
```

https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.assign has the documentation.

Comment: I did exactly as you said, but I still get the same error...